# Migrate to wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, migration

I have an old website with an old framework on PHP and mysql.

I want to migrate to wordpress.

I want to know if is possible or exist any plugin on wordpress that let me read data from mysql database and put them on page.

Other speaking, can I use the database and create pages dynamically with wordpress.

If yes please provide me a link contains a simple example to learn.

Appreciate in advance.

Comment: shortly, it's possible. but we can't suggest something, because of you need to provide more information about your `db/db structure/files you have/what you want t o use from them and etc.`, what you tryed, what errors you got...... ?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, I wanted to know if it is possible. Thanks for your answer. Is there any website with a small example that can help me? thanks

Comment: what framework do you have?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan It's really old and so I should forget it. It's pepper  (Php + mysql). Just have an example with php+mysql is enough. Thanks

Comment: you should to transwer your db handly. compare yours and wp tables, then insert into wp all info which you need. then you need to transwer html/css/js files( maybe create some templates ) and etc. if your website is not having too many datas, then it'll be faster to create new wp site, then find some theme and after add info from old site using theme tools

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Would you mind write your answer in Answer part and if you have an example add it. I want to select your answer as the answer of question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, it's possible to migrate website, which used some framework to wordpress cms. But there isn't any tools, which can do it for any framework type. Each website is differ with it's structure, pages, logics and goals.

For some cases there is plugins, extentions, which transfered the whole website from one framework to another.

But you should to know, that it can not be done 100% transfered without any losing.

Main migrate to wordpress is going so:

1.Compare databases and with sql commands insert into wodpress db information of posts/pages/users/products and etc., [which will be inserted as it need wordpress to work with theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

2.The second step is migrate static files to wordpress, such as html/css/js and make them work dinamically using wordpress functions, file structure and etc.

Please note, that if your framework have not many datas, it will be faster to just install new wordpress into server, find some theme, which will suit you, create posts/pages as you want and after it replace some information from old website